# How to handle wildcards within a text search of a string

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm using PowerShell to run some routine operations on data within a spreadsheet. We run in a 'secure environment' so I cannot have macro-enabled spreadsheets or natively execute ps1 scripts in PowerShell, but I can execute from the ISE environment, which works just fine.

I would like PowerShell to find "D - [7 digits] " (trailing space is important) and replace it with "D - [same 7 digits][line break]". The rest of my script is working as expected:

```
$File = "C:\Users\Stu\Desktop\test.xlsx"
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $true
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($file)
$Worksheets = $Workbooks.Worksheets
$Worksheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$0 = $WorkSheet.Columns(1).Replace("000000"," ")
$I = $WorkSheet.Columns.Replace(" I - ","`nI - ")
$R = $WorkSheet.Columns.Replace(" R - ","`nR - ")
$D = $WorkSheet.Columns.Replace(" D - ","`nD - ")
```

The problem I'm having is that it isn't happy to interpret wildcards as wildcards when used within the string search. I've given it a crack using `` ` `` to have PowerShell treat them as wildcards instead of explicit contents of the string but that hasn't gone so well. e.g:

```
$T = $WorkSheet.Columns.Replace("D - `?`?`?`?`?`?`? ","D - `?`?`?`?`?`?`?`n")
```

Comment: while you **_are_** using PoSh to control excel, the `.Replace()` command you are using appears to be the one in excel, not the PoSh `.Replace()` method. you may want to add the `excel` tag to your post. ////// from what i can tell, the closest you can get without adding anything is "filters".

Comment: Yep - but at least from my perspective, it seems to be more a question of 'how do i properly input X so that powershell reads it how i want it to' than anything actually excel-specific

Comment: As far as applying filters, i can see how it would work if i could filter out integers (which it would then be able to read as "D - [any other character after this] and insert a line break), but i dont really know how to achieve that. Is there an example or a similar question? My google-fu is returning nothing

Comment: i would either --- add an `excel` tag to your question, OR restate it without the excel stuff in it, OR close/delete this question and make a new one that is specific to one or the other. for instance, asking about how to use excel filters would be a good question. [*grin*]